# Unloading multiple libraries

Tags: c++, windows, dll, reference-counting

I am working with a tool (certutil.exe) which is loading two provider DLLs we have written, a CSP DLL and a CNG DLL.  Both of those will load another DLL we wrote, providing the PKCS11 functions.  That DLL also establishes sessions to the crypto hardware.

Each DLL can be used independently in different scenarios, or can be loaded together, as is the case here.

When certutil is finished, it will unload each DLL.  The problem is (and it was undetected till now), each DLL will unload the pkcs 11 library.  When the first unloads, all sessions are closed and the handles rendered invalid. When the second DLL goes to use them, the program crashes as the handles no longer reference the pkcs11 lib.  If I avoid freeing the pkcs11 lib, then I leak resources within the hardware.

My thought was to implement some form of reference counting, but, I am unsure of where to place it.  It would almost seem necessary for the pkcs11 lib to count the # of times it has been loaded and make that available to any "higher level" dll which wishes to inquire about the count.  If the count is > 1, then decrement the count.  If count == 1, then unload the dll and free resources.

Feels "not right" to me though... I must be missing something, some concept or something. This cannot be the first case of one app loading two intermediate DLLs, each of which loads a common third DLL and then requiring cleanup.

Comment: `::LoadLibrary` is already referenced counted (so is implicit loading), how are you loading/unloading the DLLs?

Comment: Call C_Finalize, then FreeLibrary. But, the second DLL doesn't know the first did that, so it's handles are now invalid, having had the rug pulled from underneath.

Comment: From the docs (I guess I have the right one - If not please link to the correct one.) _"C_Finalize() should never be called by libraries. By convention, applications are responsible for calling C_Finalize() to close out a session."_  source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4863/chapter2-9d/index.html